# Iam trying to append items into dictionary in swift but nothing is getting inserted. Please Guide

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, closures, self

[image]> Iam trying to insert values into dictionary . I tried 2 ways one in which the 2 variables are used and other in which i directly pass the value inside dictionary . Both are not working

```
for index in 0..<classes.count{
                var classification = classes[index].className
                var score = classes[index].score
                //not working
                self.classificationDictionary[classification] = score

                //not working
                self.classificationDictionary[classes[index].className] = classes[index].score
            }
```

> After the closure this seems to work. I dont understand how to append values into dictionary .

```
classificationDictionary["abc"] = 131
        print("dictionary : ",classificationDictionary)
        print(classificationDictionary.count)
```

Comment: what is the type for `self.classificationDictionary `

Comment: Is your code in closure?

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee : 
var classificationDictionary : [String:Double] = [:]

Comment: @Mukesh yes it is in closure. 
iam able to do the same thing with array and it works. 
for index in 0..<classes.count{
                  self.classificationArray.append(classes[index].className)
                }

but not with dictionary

Comment: Define "doesn't work". How do you know it's not working? In what way isn't it working?

Comment: @rmaddy i dont know whether it is working or not . Iam absolutely a beginner. Just posted a screenshot have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
classificationDictionary.updateValue(classes[index].score, forKey: classes[index].className)
```

you code will be :

```
for index in 0..<classes.count{
                var classification = classes[index].className
                var score = classes[index].score
                classificationDictionary.updateValue(score, forKey: classification)

            }
```

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var classes = [
        AnyClass(name: "pizza", score: 2.0),
        AnyClass(name: "sushi", score: 3.0),
        AnyClass(name: "potatoe", score: 4.0)
    ]
    var classificationDictionary: [String: Double]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        any()
    }

    func any() {
        classificationDictionary = [String: Double]()
        for index in 0..<classes.count {
            if let name = classes[index].name, let score = classes[index].score {
                classificationDictionary.updateValue(score, forKey: name)
            }
            print(classificationDictionary)
        }
    }

}
```

code of custom class:

```
class AnyClass: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var score: Double?

    init(name: String?, score: Double?) {
        if let name = name {
            self.name = name
        }
        if let score = score {
            self.score = score
        }
    }
}
```

result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D64p.png)

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried what u told. but it is still not adding the value in dictionary .Tried debugging,  The classes seems to work it shows 12 found but the index is not changing.

Comment: @user9473922, is the classes - array of custom objects? every object in classes consist of name: String and score: Double?

Comment: no ,  there might be more objects inside of classes . 

[VisualRecognitionV3.ClassResult(className: "pizza", score: Optional(0.68300000000000005), typeHierarchy: nil) 

reponse is usually like this. and iam tapping into the classname and score

Comment: @user9473922, I edited my answer, this code worked. check it. I implement array of custom objects, and insert objects into dictionary. on screenshot u will see how dictionary edited